# Why is children prop undefined, despite setting it in defaultProps?

Tags: reactjs, ecmascript-6, react-proptypes

I'd like to set PropTypes validation for my React component to warn if there are no children. But when I follow the PropTypes syntax [recommended by the React docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html#requiring-single-child), I get this error thrown:

> prop type `children` is invalid; it must be a function, usually from the `prop-types` package, but received `undefined`.

When I step through in the Chrome debugger, I see that `children` is `undefined` when the validation is performed. But I specifically set `children` in `defaultProps`, so why is it `undefined`?  I've tried several different values for `defaultProps.children`, including `[]` and `''`. All of them produced the same error.

Note that my app works OK. It's only `PropTypes` validation that is failing.

Below is a simplified version of the problematic code. Note that I'm using static properties to define `defaultProps` (as [recommended by Dan Abramaov](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/3725#issuecomment-355965170)). I'm using `create-react-app` so I have the Babel transform to enable the default class properties syntax.

```
import React, { Fragment } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types'
import { TabContent, TabPane, Nav, NavItem, NavLink } from 'reactstrap';
import classnames from 'classnames';

export class Tab extends React.Component {

  static propTypes = {
    name: PropTypes.string.isRequired,
    children: PropTypes.node.required,
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    name: null,
    children: ''
  }

  render () { 
    return (
      <Fragment>
        {this.props.children}
      </Fragment>
    )
  }
}

export default class TabSet extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      activeTab: 0
    };
  }

  // TODO: limit to only Tab child elements. 
  static propTypes = {
    children: PropTypes.node.required,
  }

  static defaultProps = {
    children: ''
  }

  toggle = (tab) => {
    if (this.state.activeTab !== tab) {
      this.setState({
        activeTab: tab
      });
    }
  }

  render() { 
    return (
      <Fragment>
        <Nav tabs>
          {this.props.children.map((tab,i) => 
            <NavItem key={i} style={{cursor: 'pointer'}}>
              <NavLink
                className={classnames({ active: this.state.activeTab === i })}
                onClick={() => { this.toggle(i); }}
              >
                { tab.props.name }
              </NavLink>
            </NavItem>
          )}
        </Nav>
        <TabContent activeTab={this.state.activeTab}>
          {this.props.children.map((tab,i) => 
            <TabPane key={i} tabId={i}>
              {tab}
            </TabPane>
          )}
        </TabContent>
      </Fragment>
    );
  }
}
```

If it matters, here's a simplified example of how these components are used:

```
import React from 'react';
import TabSet, {Tab} from './TabSet';
import HomeTab from './HomeTab';
import FriendsTab from './FriendsTab';
import HangTimesTab from './HangTimesTab';

export default class MainContainer extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <TabSet>
          <Tab name="Home">
            <HomeTab /> 
          </Tab>
          <Tab name="Hang Times">
            <HangTimesTab />
          </Tab>
          <Tab name="Friends">
            <FriendsTab />
          </Tab>
        </TabSet>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Where you used `Tab`?

Comment: @ArupRakshit - I just appended this info to my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The error message is a little confusing, but it refers to the prop-type declaration for `children` (i.e. `PropTypes.node.required`), which is `undefined` because of a typo. It should be `PropTypes.node.isRequired`.